# Java/JSP - Permanent Counter

Tags: java, jsp

How could you keep a permanent counter of the number of visitors to a web page, regardless of how many times the server is reset?

I can think a few but not sure if they would keep permanent count.

1) Avoid global variables.
2) Cookies
3) Session

Answer (score 4):

Cookies are user-specific, and any variables or session state will not survive a reboot.

Options that could work are either to use a database and keep your count there, or to update a file on the server's filesystem and keep a count there.

Answer (score 1):

Use a third party web counter.  There are many free ones available.

Answer (score 0):

Add a scheduled job to back the number up to a file every day or so.

You can find a simple schedule example that you can modify to your needs here: http://oreilly.com/java/archive/quartz.html

You would need to read it only when restarting the server